# Normalize whitespace and other plain-text formatting routines

Tags: javascript, formatting, text-editor

**Background:**

The language is JavaScript. The goal is to find a library or pre-existing code to do low-level plain-text formatting.

I can write it myself, but why re-invent the wheel. The issue is: it is tough to determine if a "wheel" is out there, since any search for JavaScript libraries pulls up an ocean of HTML-centric stuff. I am not interested in HTML necessarily, just text.

**Example:**

I need a JavaScript function that changes this:

*BEFORE*:

```
nisi ut aliquip | ex ea commodo consequat duis |aute irure dolor in
esse cillum dolore | eu fugiat nulla pariatur |excepteur sint occa
in culpa qui | officia deserunt mollit anim id |est laborum
```

... into this ...

*AFTER:*

```
nisi ut aliquip    | ex ea commodo consequat duis    | aute irure dolor in      
esse cillum dolore | eu fugiat nulla pariatur        | excepteur sint occa
in culpa qui       | officia deserunt mollit anim id | est laborum
```

**Question:**

Does it exist, a JavaScript library that is non-html-web-development-centric that has functions for normalizing spaces in delimited plain text, justifying and spacing plain text?

**Rationale:**

Investigating JavaScript for use in a programmer's text editor.

Comment: Why is this tagged emacs & vim?  JavaScript is not an extension language to either Emacs or vim.

Comment: Heh, well, you can already do what you want inside Emacs with `C-u M-x align-regexp \(|\) RET -1 RET 1 RET y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `String` methods are really low-level, but you can build your own methods based on them. To make this task simpler, you can use existing string manipulation libraries like [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#readme), or at least get some inspiration there.

Here's a solution to your example problem, tested in Firefox 36 and Chrome 43:

http://jsfiddle.net/46a7bexs/7/

The basic idea is to split the entire text into an array of lines, then split them on every `|` character (while stripping whitespace) and store everything in a variable similar to a table (actually a 2-dimensional array).

In the next step, it iterates over all "cells" and figures out the maximum string length per column.

Finally, entries are padded to the maximum column width and joined back to gether.

I'm sure it could be done with less code and more efficient, but since no one posted a solution to that problem, I thought I share my straight-forward code.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard on any since what you're attempting is probably no too popular.

You may have to build your own function based on [JavaScript's built-in string functions](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html).

Answer (score -1):

Sure, most of the stuff out there is geared for use in browsers, but essentially anything where functions are added to the String prototype should be helpful to you. Have a look at some of the functions here:

http://code.delacap.com/p/js-methods/docs/string.html

Then you can add your own:

```
String.prototype.myFunc = function(){ 
    //...
};

"someStr".myfunc();
```

Comment: I don't see how this is helpful or even applicable to the OP.